# Parse 3 table columns with hpricot

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hpricot

I got an HTML document with pretty simple table like this

```
<table>
<tr><th>Country</th><th>Date</th></tr>

<tr>
    <td><b><a href="/calendar/?region=BE">Belgium</a></b></td>
    <td align="right"><a href="/date/04-20/">20 April</a> <a href="/year/2001/">2001</a></td>
    <td>(original release)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><b><a href="/calendar/?region=BE">Belgium</a></b></td>
    <td align="right"><a href="/date/04-25/">25 April</a> <a href="/year/2001/">2001</a></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><b><a href="/calendar/?region=FR">France</a></b></td>
    <td align="right"><a href="/date/04-27/">27 April</a> <a href="/year/2001/">2001</a></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><b><a href="/calendar/?region=CH">Switzerland</a></b></td>
    <td align="right"><a href="/date/05-25/">25 May</a> <a href="/year/2001/">2001</a></td>
    <td>(French speaking region)</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><b><a href="/calendar/?region=CZ">Czech Republic</a></b></td>
    <td align="right"><a href="/date/07-06/">6 July</a> <a href="/year/2001/">2001</a></td>
    <td>(International Film Festival)</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

First two columns are easy to parse:

```
document.search("a[@href*=calendar]").each { |country| countries << country.inner_text }
document.search("td[@align*=right]").each { |date| dates << date.inner_text }
```

But I have troubles looking up values from 3rd column. I need all of them in array, including the blank ones. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:

```
document.search("td[@align*=right]").each { |comment| comments << comment.next.next.inner_text }
```